# Pointer to structure element that is reference to variable

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Consider:

```
struct
{
  char *rcssMonitoredServices;
  int  nSomeVar;
} appinfo;
```

In conventional use:

```
appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices=strdup("something");
```

However now consider:

```
char *RefToStructVar[]=
{
  appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices,
  "\0"
};
```

The intent being that we may perform operations against appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices using the RegToStructVar[0] pointer.

There are good reasons why I have variables pointed to within arrays.  In cases of integer variables, we're A-OK.  Pointers to *char are quite different.

If I am doing the same technique against appinfo.nSomeVar

```
int *varpointers[] =
{
    &appinfo.nSomeVar,
    0
};

varpointers[0]=196;
printf("%i",appinfo.nSomeVar) // -> "196"
```

I thought that, given  RefToStructVar[0] contains a pointer to the appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices, doing things like

```
RefToStructVar[0]=strdup("something");
```

Would be identical to:

```
appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices=strdup("something");
```

But no.

This

```
RefToStructVar[0]=strdup("something");
```

segfaults.

Perhaps basic.. but at the moment I am muddled.

--

### later

Here's what segfaults:

```
    struct 
    {
        char *cVar;
        int n;
    } mystruct;

    char *aVars[]=
    {
        mystruct.cVar,
        "\0"
    };

    aVars[0]=strdup("something");
```

This works:

```
    struct 
    {
        char *cVar;
        int n;
    } mystruct;

    char **aVars[]=
    {
        &mystruct.cVar,
        "\0"
    };

    *aVars[0]=strdup("something");
```

Comment: Your question is unnecessarily complicated. Can you simply show a complete example that segfaults ?

Comment: @cnicutar Edited into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RefToStructVar[0]=strdup("something");
```

Is not identical to

```
appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices=strdup("something");
```

Because although the two pointers point to the same memory, they are two different pointers, and assigning to one of them will not change the other.

Also, there is absolutely no reason why `RefToStructVar[0] = anything` should segfault unless `RefToStructVar` is not an array but an invalid pointer or something. I think you are misdiagnosing the crash site.

You say:

> The intent being that we may perform operations against appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices using the RegToStructVar[0] pointer.

However, that's not what it's doing. It's simply copying the pointer from `appinfo` into the array. You can do operations on the string such as changing a character that way, but if you assign to either one, they become independent. You need a pointer to a pointer if you want to do that:

```
char** RegToStructVar[] = {
    &appinfo.rcssMonitoredServices
};
```

Comment: I see your point.  My intent is to reach the structure variable.  Pointer to pointer?

Comment: @MarkRichards yes, just got that part in.

Comment: That's the ticket.  Then: *RegToStructVar[0]=strdup("something");  
Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MarkRichards yes, that's it exactly.